# Add listener to an Image

Tags: java, image, jpanel, listener

Helo dear stackoverflow people :)

My project:  I have to make an editor for electrical circuits .
My problem: I created a mirrored text which I drag onto an Image,which is then put into the EditorPanel in my program(Jpanel). I want to be able to move this mirrored text with my mouse and be able to add listeners to it.

I tried to create another JPanel ,put the image in it, then put this new JPanel to the EditorPanel but I get nullpointerException and I dont know why. Please help
Thank you

Code:

```
@Override 
      public void drawMirroredText(Graphics g3,ScrollPanel scrollpanel){ 


      Image OSC=null;

      try{
       OSC= ImageIO.read(new File("C:/Users/transparent.png"));//put transparent background to my image
      }catch(Exception e ){
          System.out.println("Cant load bufferedimages transparent background");
      }


      Graphics OSG = OSC.getGraphics();



      OSG.setColor(getForeground()); //color for text
      OSG.setFont(getFont());

      FontMetrics fm = OSG.getFontMetrics(getFont());
      int xImage = (100 - fm.stringWidth(this.text)) /2;
      int yImage = (100 + fm.getAscent() - fm.getDescent()) / 2;


        System.out.println("X is "+xImage);
         System.out.println("Y is "+yImage);
      OSG.drawString(text, xImage, yImage);
    OSG.dispose();




     // g3.drawImage(OSC, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, null);//EditorPanel graphics


    JPanel panel=new JPanel();

    Graphics panelG=panel.getGraphics();

    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));


    Graphics2D g2dpanel=(Graphics2D) panelG;

     g2dpanel.drawImage(OSC, 100, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100, panel);//draw image with mirrored text



    scrollpanel.add(panel);//Add new Jpanel to EditorPanel



  }
```

Exceptions:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>    java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Panels.ScrollPanel$Text.drawMirroredText(ScrollPanel.java:2336)   at
>   Panels.ScrollPanel.drawallnodes(ScrollPanel.java:648)     at
>   Panels.ScrollPanel.paintComponent(ScrollPanel.java:359)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5219)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1529)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1452)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1249)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5167)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4978)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:808)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(RepaintManager.java:796)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:796)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:769)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:718)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1100(RepaintManager.java:62)   at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1677)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

Comment: Use your debugger to figure out what is `null`.

Comment: Seems a bit odd to put some arbitrary image in your `Users` directory, `Users/XXXXXX/` would seem more "correct". Are you sure that is the correct path to the image? Does your program even have the correct permissions to read from there?

Comment: The image is elsewhere, that path is only for information, and yes with my correct path the image is loaded

Comment: You should **NOT** load the image each time that you are painting. You should **NOT** create a new component *while* you are painting. And most importantly: You should **NOT** call `getGraphics()` on a component. There's too much wrong to give further helpful hints, I guess...

Comment: okey marco I thought of this bit also,but with the getGraphics option i am not sure, because the Images OSG is also constructed like that